# Name self is not defined

Tags: python, class

Write a class called Rock_paper_scissors that implements the logic of the game Rockpaper-scissors. For this game the user plays against the computer for a certain number of
rounds. Your class should have fields for the how many rounds there will be, the current
round number, and the number of wins each player has. There should be methods for getting
the computer’s choice, finding the winner of a round, and checking to see if someone has one
the (entire) game. You may want more methods.

I've created various methods. One for cpu random choice, other for player input, another for gaming conditions and the last one to see who's player won.

```
import random


class Rock_paper_scissors:


    def __init__(self,player_points,cpu_points):

        self.game = [] #empty list with all possible cpu & player ans
        self.cpu_points = cpu_points #counts the number of cpu points
        self.player_points = player_points #counts the number of player points

    def cpu_round(self):

        return random.choice(self.game)


    def player_round(self):

        return input('Final answer\n')


    def games(self,rounds,player_points,cpu_points):

        turns = 0 #number of turns that have passed

        while turns < rounds:
            cpu_ans = self.cpu_round()
            print(cpu_ans)
            player_ans = self.player_round()
            #game conditions to be met
            if cpu_ans == player_ans:
                print('Draw')
                self.player_points += 1
                self.cpu_points += 1
                turns += 1

            elif self.player_ans == 'rock' and self.cpu_ans == 'paper':
                print('Cpu won round')
                self.cpu_points += 1
                turns += 1

            elif self.player_ans == 'rock' and self.cpu_ans == 'scissors':
                print('Player won round')
                self.player_points += 1
                turns += 1

            elif self.player_ans == 'paper' and self.cpu_ans == 'rock':
                print('Player won round')
                self.player_points += 1
                turns += 1

            elif self.player_ans == 'paper' and self.cpu_ans == 'scissors':
                print('Cpu won round')
                self.cpu_points += 1
                turns += 1

            elif self.player_ans == 'scissors' and self.cpu_ans == 'rock':
                print('Cpu won round')
                self.cpu_points += 1
                turns += 1

            else:
                print('Player won round')
                self.player_points += 1
                turns += 1



    def winning_conditions(self):

        if self.player_points == self.cpu_points:
            print('Draw',self.player_points,self.cpu_points)

        elif self.player_points > self.cpu_points:
            print('Player won the game with',self.player_points,self.cpu_points)

        else:
            print('Cpu won the game with',self.cpu_points,self.player_points)



results = Rock_paper_scissors(player_points,cpu_points)
results.game = ['rock','paper','scissors']
rounds = int(input('How many round will the game have?'))
print(results.cpu_round())
print(results.player_round())
print(results.games(rounds))
print(results.winning_conditions())
```

In my sentence `results = Rock_paper_scissors` it says it's missing two arguments (`player_points` and `cpu_points`). But when I put those two arguments it keeps my giving an error saying playing points not defined.

**input**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "main.py", line 91, in 
>           results = Rock_paper_scissors(player_points,cpu_points)
>       NameError: name 'player_points' is not defined

Comment: full traceback of error please

Comment: where is `player_points` at line 83 `Rock_paper_scissors(player_points,cpu_points)` defined

Comment: You need to define `player_points` before you can pass it to `Rock_paper_scissors`, so, add `player_points = 0` just before the `Rock_paper_scissors(...` and then also `cpu_points = 0`

Comment: @Ashwani that is why i put self.player_points..

Comment: @jojo i thought i did that in my first instance method

Comment: @LuísLopes See Marko's answer to get the code to work. What is happening here is that you're confusing the names of the `Arguments` of the `__init__` method with defined `variables` in the code.

Comment: @LuísLopes you do *not* initiate `player_points` in your `__init__` you do initiate `self.player_points`, an attribute of a `Rock_paper_scissors` instance. To initiate it you use `player_points`, a variable you **must** have defined before. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the definition for player points in line 83. So the correct way would be for you game start to put:

```
player_points = 0
cpu_points = 0
results = Rock_paper_scissors(player_points,cpu_points)
```

From your example, I would recommend you study the basics of Python to a greater detail.

Comment: If my code does not know what player points is then why initiate that variable in my init method. I thought wrong that by doing that i had access to that variable in other methods

Comment: Your variables are accessible exclusively in the scope you define them. So writing `self.points` allows you to access that variable exclusively within the `Rock_paper_scissors` class or using the instance of that class ex: `result.player_points`.

Comment: @LuísLopes variable `player_points` inside `__init__` is local variable and has nothing to do with variable which you use in `results = Rock_paper_scissors(player_points,cpu_points)`

Comment: that is what i wanted to hear thanks :DD. By the ways i'm following the book a practical introduction to python. So i think more basic book i cannot find xd

Comment: @LuísLopes It's fine that you're working through a book. But there's always more stuff to read about on the internet as well. One thing you should look into that might explain this problem further is to learn more about `Namespace` and `scope` of different variables in Python.